# How to share cached apollo-client data with another query

Tags: reactjs, shopify, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using `apollo-client@2.3.x` (& `react-apollo@2.1.x`), with the standard `InMemoryCache`, to query a Shopify store via their GraphQL Storefront API.

I have two queries: 1. `getProducts` (in `<Home />`), and 2. `getProduct($id)` (in `<ProductDetail />`). In the scenario starts on `<Home />`, then clicks on a product, I'd like the `<ProductDetail />` component to show the cached response from query 1 before query 2 runs.

- Demo: https://shopify-storefront-example-rdfwtslzng.now.sh/
- Source: https://shopify-storefront-example-rdfwtslzng.now.sh/_src

You can see in the demo, when clicking on the product, that `data` is an empty `{}` in the console, until the second network request is complete. I assumed that it would be cached, as the queries share the same `__typename`, and use the "node" structure.

Can someone enlighten me here, (A) why it doesn't work, and (B) how can I make it so?

---

Here's a summary of the two queries:

1: "**getProducts**" (e.g. used in a `<Home />` component)

```
query getProducts {
  shop {
    products(first: 20) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          ... on Product {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2: "**getProduct**" (e.g. used in a `<ProductDetail />` component)

```
query getProduct($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Product {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The GraphQL client cannot make assumptions about the implementations of the resolvers even when for a human the API seem to follow an easy pattern and the behaviour of the queries seems trivial. You need to help out a bit with a [Cache Redirect](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#cacheRedirect).

Okay, I tried this here for you. I don't really work with these Relay APIs but it should be working quite similarly to the example.

```
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      getProduct: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => ({
        __typename: 'Node',
        node: getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Product', id: args.id }),
      }),
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how cacheRedirects could work with this Relay-style pagination structure. (e.g. There's no "products" or "product" query key). Any hints here of what I'd need to write?

Comment: Okay, actually you can't use readFragment because you can't access the apollo-client. Maybe the above will work where you _fake_ the node response. Alternatively you could try and look up the node (assuming it also has an id)

Comment: Thanks for your help. `readFragment` proved quite useful once I'd converted both queries to use the same fragment.