# Read query from apollo cache with a query that doesn't exist yet, but has all info stored in the cache already

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I have a graphql endpoint where this query can be entered:

```
fragment ChildParts {
  id
  __typename
}

fragment ParentParts {
  __typename
  id
    children {
   edges{
       node {
         ...ChildParts 
       }
   }
}

query {
  parents {
    edges
      nodes {
        ...ParentParts
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When executed, it returns something like this:

```
"data": {
  "edges": [
     "node": {
       "id": "<some id for parent>",
       "__typename": "ParentNode",
       "children": {
         "edges": [
           node: {
             "id": "<some id for child>",
             "__typename": "ChildNode"
           },
           ...
         ]
       }
     },
     ...   
  ]
}
```

Now, with apollo client, after a mutation, I can read this query from the cache, and update / add / delete any ParentNode, and also any ChildNode, but I have to go over the structure returned by this query.

Now, I'm looking for a possibility to get a list of ChildNodes out of the cache (which has those already, as the cache is created as a flat list), to make the update of nested data a bit easier. Is there a possibility of reading a query out of the cache, without having read the same query from the server before?

Comment: Apollo Client has so called [cache redirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#cacheRedirect) that you can use. See also my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839798/3849167

Comment: Can you add cache redirects for a list though? Or can you write a null value to the cache for an ID? Because my use case involves deleting a node, and I want to prevent traversing the whole parent tree to find the child to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the client's `readFragment` method to retrieve any one individual item from the cache. This just requires the id and a fragment string.

```
const todo = client.readFragment({
  id,
  fragment: gql`
    fragment fooFragment on Foo {
      id
      bar
      qax
    }
  `,
})
```

Note that `id` here is the cache key returned by the dataIdFromObject function -- if you haven't specified a custom function, then (provided the __typename and id or _id fields are present) the default implementation is just:

```
${result.__typename}:${result.id || result._id}
```

If you provided your own dataIdFromObject function, you'll need to provide whatever id is returned by that function.

As @Herku pointed out, depending on the use case, it's also possible to use cache redirects to utilize data cached for one query when resolving another one. This is configured as part of setting up your `InMemoryCache`:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      book: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Book', id: args.id })
    },
  },
})
```

Unfortunately, as of writing this answer, I don't believe there's any method to delete a cached item by id. There's on going discussion [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/4) around that point (original issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/621)).